# Error running laravel migrates in docker container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm creating php/nginx and mysql images in docker-compose, but when accessing the container and trying to run the laravel migrations, it shows this return

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  laravel-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql-app:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABSE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: laravel
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My laravel conexion .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql-app
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=laravel
```

I already tried to use the commands but it didn't work:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Does anyone know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose the mysql port is 3306, in your .env it's 33060 and you should add a dependency to your 'laravel-app' to make sure that the mysql container is started as well:

```
laravel-app:
    [...]
    depends_on:
        - mysql-app
```

Everything else looks good for me.